# vscode debugger with karma and angular 4

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, karma-runner

I am trying to connect the vscode debugger to my angular 4 unit tests that use karma as the runner.

I am using kamra 1.7.1 and angular 4.

My launch.json looks like this:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
      {
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "attach",
        "name": "Attach Karma Chrome",
        "address": "localhost",
        "port": 9333,
        "pathMapping": {
          "/": "${workspaceRoot}",
          "/base/": "${workspaceRoot}/"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

My karma.conf.js looks like this:

```
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/config/configuration-file.html
const join = require('path').join;

module.exports = function ( config )
{
    config.set( {
        basePath: '',
        frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular/cli'],
        plugins: [
            require('karma-jasmine'),
            require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
            require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
            require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
            require('karma-verbose-reporter'),
            require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma')
        ],
        files: [
            { pattern: 'src/test.ts' }
        ],
        coverageIstanbulReporter: {
            reports: [ 'html', 'lcovonly' ],
            fixWebpackSourcePaths: true,
            dir: join(__dirname, 'metrics', 'coverage')
        },
        angularCli: {
            environment: 'dev'
        },
        reporters: ['progress', 'verbose'],
        port: 9876,
        logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,
        autoWatch: true,
        customLaunchers: {
            ChromeCI: {
              base: 'ChromeHeadless',
              flags: ['--no-sandbox', '--headless']
            }
        },
        browsers: ['ChromeCI'],
        singleRun: false
    } );
};
```